# Using setParams with include

Tags: php

I'm trying to edit a template system so where I can use params such as [*title*] and it'll show my title in the included page. But I also want to be able to use php code inside of it and be able to execute that code. But I am having difficult getting them both to work at the same time.

I have tried to use include instead of file_get_Contents but when I use include, the params no longer work. However when I use file_get_contents the php doesnt work, and doesnt show.

My code:

```
class Template {

    public function __construct($directory){
        $this->dir = $directory;
    }

    public function setPage($pageName){
        $this->directory = 'lib/' . $this->dir . '/' . $pageName . '.php';
        if(file_exists($this->directory)) {
            $Content = file_get_contents($this->directory);
        }
    }
    public function newParam($trans, $val){
        $this->param['[*' . $trans . '*]'] = $val;
    }

    public function setParams($element){
        $element = str_replace(array_keys($this->param), array_values($this->param), $element);
        return $element;
    }

    public function Create(){
        die($this->setParams($Content));
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help. Thanks